# SSD does not mount to designated directory

Tags: mount, hard-drive, ssd

I have 4 SSDs and I was able to mount all 4 of them with commands on Terminal:

```
sudo mkfs.xfs /dev/nvme0n1p1

sudo mount -t xfs -o discard /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/SSD_1
```

However since early this week, 1 of the 4 SSDs just neglects the mount command (the other 3 still works perfectly). After the mount command I see "Disks" app content:

"XFS - Not Mounted"

If I click the "Play" button in "Disks" it would show in content

"XFS - mounted at /media/user/63a29c51-e5e8-4a9f-a8e7-2ee0834a7c4e"

String "63a29....." is the SSD's UUID. Whereas if my command works I expect to see:

"XFS - mounted at /mnt/SSD_1"

Any advice please?

Thanks very much!

Comment: What is the error message that appears in the terminal when you execute the mount command on that partition?

Comment: There appears no error message after I execute the mount command, just like the other 3 SSDs. While the other 3 SSDs would be mounted afterwards, while SSD_1 did not.

Comment: Did you perhaps have a typo and mount two at SSD_1?  I also like to label all partitions, so any that I do not regularly mount with fstab, get mounted using label. To add labels I use gparted, disks or command line.

Comment: Pretty sure I typed the correct label on the mount command, as I have tried a dozen times. Thanks for the advice I will add labels to all the other drives.

Comment: To update everyone, I simply created a /mnt/SSD_5 directory and was then able to mount SSD1 to it. Still not working if I try to mount SSD1 to /mnt/SSD_1 for some reasons.